# What is the relation between enthalpy, ionization potential, internal energy and HOMO/LUMO?

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, hydrogen-bonds

Is there any relation between enthalpy, ionization potential, internal energy and HOMO/LUMO?

I am dehydrogenating a molecule and I need to study the enthalpy of dehydrogenation. If I get any relation between above properties, then I can conclude something for my results.

Comment: See [Koopmans' theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopmans%27_theorem) for a relationship between ionization potential and the HOMO/LUMO gap.

Comment: I want  enthalpy and internal energy (ground state energy obtained from DFT code) into the equation.

Comment: Where are you stuck so far? Do you know the definitions of these terms individually? Do you have some guesses as to how these properties would be related?

Comment: I have some guess that if I remove one H2 from the hydrocarbon then the internal energy (DFT energy) will change and hence HOMO-LUMO will change. SO there should be something that relates the enthalpy of dehydrogenation and HOMO-LUMO.

Comment: You could feel free to plot these properties and see if there is a relationship, but there isn't going to be a clean answer to your problem I fear.

Comment: Koopmans' theorem doesn't apply in DFT

Comment: I've seen people tuning functionals (range-separated) to match HOMO energy to ionization potential.

Comment: Can you please provide some link that establish such relations.

Comment: @romaichenko If you're able to find those functionals, perhaps you can put the reference in an answer, since this question has been left unanswered for quite some time now.

Comment: astha, I assume your question was to @romaichenko is that correct? In the future it would be helpful if you could tag people so that we know to whom your question is being directed. Roma, do you think you can write an answer with the references that you say that you've seen?

Comment: what is it about dehydrogenation that is of importance for your results? There is a relationship between the change in free energy from reactants to products and the rate of a reaction (this is known as a linear free energy relationship).